# Ionic- Hide button in Nav bar in a specific view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I searched about this topic, but i didn't find a solution for fixing the issue.
Basically I am building a app with login which has a nav icon also (like in bootstrap).
What i need to accomplish here is, i want to hide that particular button in the login page only.
 **Index.html**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <!-- right -->
        <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-hide="isInLogin"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

**controller.js**

```
controller('LoginController',function($scope){
  //$scope.isInLogin=true;
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter',function(){
  console.log("inLogin");
    $scope.isInLogin=true;
  });
});
```

I have tried like this also

```
controller('LoginController',function($scope){
     $scope.isInLogin=true;

    });
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginController'
  })
  .state('tabs',{
    url:'/tabs',
    comtroller:'TabController',
    templateUrl:'templates/tabs.html',
    abstract:true
  })
```

I am still in the learning level, any idea about how it can be achieved?

Comment: check your app.js and your state hierarchies, put the login page the first one. For example. state name of login page is 'login' and state of homepage is 'app.homepage'.

Comment: login page is in the top   @MissakBoyajian , Updated the question please check